# Closing all pipes of a process

Tags: shell, pipe, c++, fork

I am working on making a program that will act in a similar way as a shell, but supports only foreground processes and pipes. I have multiple processes writing to the same pipe and some other properties that differ from the normal usage of pipes. Anyhow, my question is,

*Is there any easy (automatic) way to close all file descriptors of a process except the three basic ones?*

I am asking this question since I have a lot of difficulties keeping track of all file descriptors for every process. And sometimes they act in some unpredictable ways to me. It could be also because of the fact that I don't have a very thorough understanding of them.

Comment: shell script or C?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention. It's C++.

Comment: add an extract of your code...

Comment: You should really learn how to keep track of the file descriptors in use.  You could look up the `FD_CLOEXEC` parameter for `fcntl()`, and some systems allow `O_CLOEXEC` on `open()`.  However, to apply that, you need to know the file descriptor so that you can ensure it will be closed automatically when your process execs another program.  However, that may not be your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any easy way(automatic) to close all file descriptors of a process except the three basic ones?

The normal way to do this is to simply iterate over all of them and close them:

```
for (i = getdtablesize(); i > 3;) close(--i);
```

That's already a one-liner. It doesn't get any more "automatic" than that.

> I am asking this question since I have a lot of difficulty keeping track of all file descriptors for every process.

It will be worth your time to think about the life cycle of each file descriptor you open, when it gets duplicated (e.g. `dup2()` and `fork()`), how it gets used, and make sure you account for how each one is going to get closed when it is no longer needed. Papering over a problem of leaked file descriptors by indiscriminately closing them all is not going to be sustainable.

> I have multiple processes writing to the same pipe

If you do this, then you need to be aware that the order in which data arrive at the other end of the pipe is going to be unpredictable. It will be difficult to avoid corrupting the data stream.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed my problem by closing all the unnecessary file descriptors in another way but I'll keep note of this in case I need it later.

Comment: Note: POSIX says one should use `sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX)` instead of `getdtablesize()` which is non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `closefrom(3)` C library function.

From the manpage:

> The **closefrom**() system call deletes all open file descriptors greater
>   than or equal to *lowfd* from the per-process object reference table.
>   Any errors encountered while closing file descriptors are ignored.

Example usage:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    // Close everything except stdin, stdout and stderr
    closefrom(3); // Were 3 is the lowest file descriptor you wish to close

    printf("Clear of all, but the three basic file descriptors!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This works in most unices, but **requires the `libbsd` support library for Linux**.

Comment: Can you provide a URL?  Which sub-species of Linux?  I can't find it at http://linux.die.net/ which is where I usually go to find Linux manual pages.

Comment: @Lonathan Leffler You're right, on Linux it actually is only available in `libbsd` (*utility functions from BSD systems"). Only *everything else Unixy* has this as a native system or library call.

Comment: Hmmm; I wonder whether Mac OS X is _Unixy_; 10.11.4 El Capitan doesn't appear to have it (for all it is a BSD-based library).  OTOH, Solaris 10 has it (header `<stdlib.h>`), but HP-UX 11.23 does not, and AIX 6.3 does not.  Granted, the HP and IBM releases are _not_ the latest ones.

Comment: For Linux a system call called `close_range` was merged in 5.9, so expect this functionality to land in glibc and friends eventually: https://lwn.net/Articles/837816/